# Angular Animate Fade-In, Fade-Out Component

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-animate

I have the following code that I'd like to apply to a component when entering and leaving:

```
animations: [
    trigger('visibilityChanged', [
      state('in', style({opacity: 1})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({opacity: 1}),
        animate(100)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(100, style({opacity: 0}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

This is nearly identical to the example that the [Angular docs provide](https://angular.io/guide/animations#example-entering-and-leaving) but for some reason, when going from the `void => *` state, there is no fade-in.

I've also tried this in there [live examples](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/animations/eplnkr.html) page with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you checkout **ng-animate** because it has lots of animations out of the box which are easily implemented, but if want code without library that fits your purpose then use this:

```
import { trigger, animate, transition, style, state } from '@angular/animations';

export const simpleFadeAnimation = trigger('simpleFadeAnimation', [

    // the "in" style determines the "resting" state of the element when it is visible.
    state('in', style({opacity: 1})),

    // fade in when created. this could also be written as transition('void => *')
    transition(':enter', [
      style({opacity: 0}),
      animate(1000 )
    ]),

    // fade out when destroyed. this could also be written as transition('void => *')
    transition(':leave',
      animate(1000, style({opacity: 0})))
]);
```

Or if you want to trasition by "X" axis, use this:

```
import { trigger, animate, transition, style, group, query } from '@angular/animations';

export const slideInAnimation = trigger('slideInAnimation', [
   // Transition between any two states
   transition('* <=> *', [
   // Events to apply
   // Defined style and animation function to apply
   // Config object with optional set to true to handle when element not yet added to the DOM
  query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%', zIndex: 2 }), { optional: true }),
    // group block executes in parallel
    group([
      query(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
        animate('0.7s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
      ], { optional: true }),
      query(':leave', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
        animate('0.7s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
       ], { optional: true })
    ])
  ])
]);
```

After that you need to import it inside **@Component** decorator in **.ts** file. And if you want to share it trough all components inside you app then use this:

```
<div [@slideInAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 animations: [
  trigger('visibilityChanged', [
    state('in', style({
      opacity: 0
    })),
    state('out',   style({
      opacity: 1
    })),
    transition('in => out', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('out => in', animate('100ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.